# Remove Manjaro from GRUB options

Tags: dual-boot

I'm still a noob with Linux and I don't know how to use it correctly (obviously). I had Manjaro as my second OS (dual boot with Ubuntu), but I was running out of memory, and I messed up a lot. To keep things short, I deleted the Manjaro partition without actually uninstalling it (like a normal person would). But now Manjaro still shows up in the GRUB, together with Ubuntu. What should I do to fix it? I know this was really dumb and I thank you for your help.

Comment: If your Ubuntu install is working properly, and the only problem is that Manajaro is listed in GRUB, that should be fixable.  If you open a terminal and type 'sudo update-grub', then enter your password when asked, what is the output? Please [edit] your question and add this output. There is a chance that simply running this command will fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, wow! That fixed it. Thanks a lot for the help! :) If you are curious about it, I can also post the output that it gave me. Thanks again!

Comment: No, that's fine. I will post my suggestion as an answer, and you can accept it if you like. I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Ubuntu install is working properly, and the only problem is that Manjaro is listed in GRUB, that should be fixable. If you open a terminal and type `sudo update-grub`, then enter your password when prompted, there is a chance that simply running this command will fix the problem.